# Sorting DefaultDict() using key values in Python3.x

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x, ordereddictionary

I have a dict which contains values like

```
DefaultListOrderedDict([('29.970', [1, 0, 0, 0, 0]), ('100.000', [0, 1, 0, 0, 1]), ('200.000', [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]), ('60.000', [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]), ('0.750', [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]), ('25.000', [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]), ('48.000', [0, 0, 1, 0, 0])])
```

I would like to sort it with values

I tried  `for k,v in sorted(Dict.items(),reverse = True):`

But the sorting occurs in this order :

```
   ['0.750', '100.000', '200.000', '25.000', '29.970', '48.000', '60.000']
```

I don't understand the reason behind it. I would like to know the way how to sort it as :

```
   ['0.750', '25.000', '29.970', '48.000', '60.000', '100.000', '200.000']
```

Comment: Those are strings, so they are sorted lexicographical. Use float literals or use the `float` function to convert them to numbers.

Comment: It's because you're sorting the strings. First map your string dict to an int dict: dict = {int(k), v for k, v in dict}

Comment: If you want it sorted in that order, why are you using `reverse = True`?

Comment: @martineau because when I map it using a plotting library it actually plots in opposite direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert keys to float:

```
OrderedDict(sorted(your_dict.items(), key=lambda item: float(item[0])))
```

Comment: How to store it back to the keys of your_dict ? As the sorted function. Does not automatically store the sorted values in the library.